# How do I remap escape when in Sublime Text vintage mode?

Tags: vim, sublimetext

I am a vim user who is moving to Sublime text and using Vintage mode.  In my `.vimrc` I have the following line:

```
imap jk <Esc>
```

In vim, this allows me to escape out of insert mode without having to lunge for the escape key and keep my fingers on the home row.  How do I do the same thing with Sublime Text Vintage mode?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

"Vintage mode is implemented entirely via key bindings and the plugin API - feel free to browse through the Vintage package and see how it's put together. As an example, if you'd like to bind "jj" to exit insert mode, you can add this key binding:"

```
{ "keys": ["j", "j"], "command": "exit_insert_mode",
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": false },
        { "key": "setting.is_widget", "operand": false }
    ]
}
```

Just modify first line to jk if you prefer that.
[Source](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/vintage.html)

Comment: Thanks, that worked great!  I added that fragment to Default.sublime-keymap but now I am wondering if there is a better place to override the defaults.

Comment: Yup, probably better to do this in your User-specific keymap files if you don't want to mess with the defaults.  You can get there by navigating to `Preferences -> Key Bindings-User`.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using the [Vintageous](https://github.com/guillermooo/Vintageous) plugin, use [the following key binding](https://github.com/guillermooo/Vintageous/wiki/Using-jj-instead-of-Esc):

```js
{
    "keys": ["j", "k"],
    "command": "_enter_normal_mode",
    "args": {"mode": "mode_insert"},
    "context": [{"key": "vi_insert_mode_aware"}]
}
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about Vintageous.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: This also works with the more recent [Neovintageous](https://github.com/NeoVintageous/NeoVintageous) plugin.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone using [Neovintageous 1.21.0](https://blog.gerardroche.com/2020/04/29/neovintageous-1.21.0/), you can set these options in Sublime Text preferences to remap `<Esc>`

```
"vintageous_i_escape_jj": true
"vintageous_i_escape_jk": true
```

And that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Also, `Ctrl+[` works and is much easier to reach for than the `esc` key. This is in OSX at least.

Comment: It's important to note that `Ctrl+[` is already taken for un-indenting a line. `Ctrl+]` indents.

Comment: You must be talking about something other than OSX.

Comment: Yeah, I should have specified. I'm using Sublime Text 2 in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add `keys` configuration into `preference > settings` but you need to add it into `preferences > keybindings`. Add the following code below:

```
{ "keys": ["j", "j"], "command": "exit_insert_mode",
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": false },
        { "key": "setting.is_widget", "operand": false }
    ]
}
```

Save the file. Test it, it should work.

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/vintage.html#included