# sublime in vintage mode - remapping escape failing

Tags: sublimetext2, remap

I'm trying to mapp jj to escape. I'm getting an error below. Fix?

[image: “Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected trailing characters in {path}:15:1]

Comment: Don’t be too lazy to write down the error message here and read the markdown help. I’ve copied the former into image alt and made image show immediately not after opening the URL.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I remap escape when in Sublime Text vintage mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620812/how-do-i-remap-escape-when-in-sublime-text-vintage-mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should place your configuration code in `Default (OS).sublime-keymap`, not in `Preferences.sublime-settings`.

You can find it in `Sublime Text 2/Preferences/Key Bindings - User` menu.

Answer (score 0):

Open Sublime Text Keybindings Settings Default (Windows).sublime-keymap

Go to Preferences -> Key Bindings - User.

[image]

Inside your Default (OS).sublime-keymap file, add your remap..

```
[
    { "keys": ["j", "j"], "command": "exit_insert_mode",
        "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": false },
            { "key": "setting.is_widget", "operand": false }
        ]
    }
]
```